# Can I bind GoDaddy domain name to website hosted on xampp on port 8080

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, iis

I have a Windows server with IIS on port 80 and I had to make a PHP website, so I installed xampp and make the apache server run on port 8080. Now I have a domain name on GoDaddy and I need to link this domain name to my site that is run on port 8080 on Apache, to make a demo to my client

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Microsoft offers WSL on Windows Server (2019 and above) for you to host PHP/Python web apps, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server There is really no need to resort to xampp

Answer (score 0):

No. DNS doesn't tell browsers about port numbers.

Use IIS as a reverse proxy for Apache on port 80.